# how to update/refresh Progress View from a long-running non-UI Job in eclipse rcp

Tags: eclipse, multithreading, jobs, rcp

i have a long-running non-UI Job with a number of sub-tasks. each sub-task updates caption for the Job's progress entry in the Progress View via IProgressMonitor.subTask(some-caption). the Job goes through three sub-tasks before it contributes to the UI in its fourth sub-task (via Display.syncExec() of course) by creating a new IEditorPart instance. **the problem is that those initial three sub-tasks are never reflected in the Job's progress entry in the Progress View. in fact, the Job progress entry never actually appears in the Progress View until fourth sub-task.** this, of course, creates a problem for a user who is left to wonder if anything is even happening. my guess is that once the Job starts, the vm thread "broker" (sorry, not well versed in this matter) never gets a chance to switch from a non-UI Job thread to the UI thread until the former actually makes a call to the latter via Display.syncExec(). my only solution at this point is to put Job thread to sleep for about half a second right after each sub-task kicks in, thereby allowing UI thread to take over long enough to update Progress View. and while this has worked most of the time, i still get instances here and there where the Porgress View still remains empty until fourth sub-task, leading me to believe that my solution is not of a robust kind. hence, i am looking for a robust one. thank you for your time!

EDIT: example code

```
Job job = new Job("multipleTasks") {
    public IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
        monitor.beginTask("multiple tasks", IProgressMonitor.UNKNOWN);
        monitor.subTask("task1");
        monitor.worked(1);
        try { Thread.sleep(1000); } catch (Exception e) { }
        monitor.subTask("task2");
        monitor.worked(1);
        try { Thread.sleep(1000); } catch (Exception e) { }
        monitor.subTask("task3");
        monitor.worked(1);
        try { Thread.sleep(1000); } catch (Exception e) { }
        monitor.done();
        return Status.OK_STATUS;
    }
};
job.schedule();
```

Comment: Did you call `pm.beginTask(*)` and `pm.worked(*)` ?

Comment: i do not use the latter because i use pm.UNKNOWN as the second argument for the former.

Comment: AFAIK you can still use `pm.worked(*)` even if your total is unknown.  What happens when you do?

Comment: i tried it, but it did not change the undesired behavior. it seems as though i need something that will allow me to better control threading between sub-tasks. sleeping just may be it, but i am not convinced until someone more knowledgeable in that area confirms it.

Comment: You might be right, if your subtasks don't ever yield the UI thread might never get control.  `syncExec(Runnable)` includes a yield.  Does the EDIT example update the subtasks like you expect?

Comment: yes, Paul, my job layout looks exactly like that. thank you for the mod, btw. what i also realized is that there are probably three threads running at once: the UI thread, the non-UI job thread, and the non-UI thread that kicked off the job thread. so putting job thread to sleep does not guarantee UI thread kicking in all the time. which is probably why my so-called solution is not successful 100% of the time. i need a way to force-switch to a specific thread.

Comment: For others who reach this article because they have issues with updating their ui from a long running non-ui thread: the Eclipse help does not state how to get the Display and I had to use Display.getDefault().asyncExec() instead of Display.getCurrent().asyncExec() to get it working.